alternating sum of stirling of second kind multiplied by binomial $S(n,m) = \sum_{k}^{n} (-1)^{n-k}\binom{n}{k} S(k+1, m+1)$
I am trying to prove by induction $S(n,m) = \sum_{k=m}^n (-1)^{n-k}\binom{n}{k} S(k+1, m+1)$ where $S$ is the Stirling of second kind. I proved it using the formula for $S$:
$$
S(n,m) = \frac{1}{m!}\sum_{j=0}^{m}\binom{m}{j}(-1)^{m-j}j^n = \sum_{j=0}^{m}\frac{(-1)^{m-j}j^n}{j! (m-j)!}
$$
\begin{align}
\sum_{k=0}^n (-1)^{n-k}\binom{n}{k} S(k+1, m+1) &=\sum_{k=0}^{n} (-1)^{n-k}\binom{n}{k} \frac{1}{(m+1)!}\sum_{j=0}^{m+1}\binom{m+1}{j}(-1)^{m+1-j}j^{k+1} \\
&= \frac{1}{(m+1)!}\sum_{j=0}^{m+1}\binom{m+1}{j}(-1)^{m+1-j}\cdot j\cdot\sum_{k=0}^{n} (-1)^{n-k}\binom{n}{n-k}j^k \\
&= \frac{1}{(m+1)!}\sum_{j=0}^{m+1}\binom{m+1}{j}(-1)^{m+1-j}\cdot j(j-1)^n \\
&= \sum_{j=0}^{m+1}\frac{(-1)^{m+1-j}(j-1)^n}{(j-1)!(m+1-j)!} \\
&= \sum_{j=0}^{m}\frac{(-1)^{m-j}j^n}{j!(m-j)!} = S(n,m)
\end{align}
However, now I am struggling to prove this by induction and need hints. Thanks in advance.
My attempt: I am trying to do induction on $n$
$\begin{align}
S(n+1,m) &= \sum_{k=m}^{n+1} (-1)^{n+1-k}\binom{n+1}{k} S(k+1, m+1)\\
&=\sum_{k=m}^{n+1} (-1)^{n+1-k}\binom{n+1}{k} [S(k,m)+(m+1)S(k,m+1)]\\
&= \sum_{k=m}^{n+1} (-1)^{n+1-k}\binom{n+1}{k}S(k,m) + (m+1)\sum_{k=m+1}^{n+1} (-1)^{n+1-k}\binom{n+1}{k} S(k,m+1)\\
&=\sum_{k=m-1}^{n} (-1)^{n-k}\binom{n+1}{k+1} S(k+1,m) + (m+1)\sum_{k=m}^{n} (-1)^{n-k}\binom{n+1}{k+1} S(k+1,m+1)\\
&=(n+1)\sum_{k=m-1}^{n} \frac{(-1)^{n-k}}{k+1}\binom{n}{k} S(k+1,m) + (m+1)(n+1)\sum_{k=m}^{n} \frac{(-1)^{n-k}}{k+1}\binom{n}{k} S(k+1,m+1)
\end{align}
$
I am stuck at getting rid of these $(k+1)$s at the denominators

You already have a proof of this, but you now want an induction-based proof, correct?

yes for now I made unsuccessful attempts

We prove this by induction on $n$. The base case is when $n=m$, which is easy to prove. Assuming the result is true for $n$, we prove it for $n+1$ as follows:
$$
\begin{align}
&S(n+1,m)
\\&= S(n,m-1)+m\cdot S(n,m)
\\&=\sum_{k=m-1}^n(-1)^{n-k}\binom nk S(k+1,m)
   +m\cdot \sum_{k=\color{#f00}{m-1}}^n(-1)^{n-k}\binom nkS(k+1,m+1)\tag1
\\&=\sum_{k=m-1}^n(-1)^{n-k}\binom nk \Big(S(k+1,m)+m\cdot S(k+1,m+1)\Big)
\\&=\sum_{k=m-1}^n(-1)^{n-k}\binom nk \Big(\color{blue}{S(k+1,m)+(m+1)\cdot S(k+1,m+1)}-S(k+1,m+1)\Big)
\\&=\sum_{k=m-1}^n(-1)^{n-k}\binom nk \Big(S(k+2,m+1)-S(k+1,m+1)\Big)
\\&=\sum_{k=m-1}^n(-1)^{n-k}\binom nk S(k+2,m+1)
+\sum_{k=m-1}^n(-1)^{n-k+1}\binom nk S(k+1,m+1)
\\&=\sum_{k=\color{blue}m}^{\color{blue}{n+1}}(-1)^{n-(\color{blue}{k-1})}\binom n{\color{blue}{k-1}} S(\color{blue}{k+1},m+1)
+\sum_{k=\color{red}m}^{\color{red}{n+1}}(-1)^{n-k+1}\binom nk S(k+1,m+1)\tag2
\\&= \sum_{k=m}^{n+1}(-1)^{n+1-k}\left[\binom n{k-1}+\binom nk\right]S(k+1,m+1)
\\&= \sum_{k=m}^{n+1}(-1)^{n+1-k}\binom{n+1}{k}S(k+1,m+1).
\end{align}
$$
Explanations:

Apply the inductive hypothesis to both $S(n,m-1)$ and $S(n,m)$. The second summation in $(1)$ has a lower index of $\color{blue}{m-1}$, even though the inductive hypothesis calls for a lower index of $m$. This is allowed because the additional term is zero, as $S(m,m+1)=0$.

The sum of the left is reindexed. For the sum on the right, I changed the bounds of the sum from $\sum_{k=m-1}^n$ to $\sum_{k=\color{red}m}^{\color{red}{n+1}}$, which amounts to removing the $k=m-1$ term and adding in a $k=n+1$ term. This is allowed because the added and removed terms are both zero.



thanks. crystal clear
